# SQL - IN clause vs equals operator for small list

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Which should be the preferred and efficient way?

```
where @TeamId in (Team1Id, Team2Id)
```

or

```
where @TeamId=Team1Id or @TeamId=Team2Id
```

I am using sql server 2008.

**Edit**

When I checked execution plans, both the queries showed that they are using indexes and same execution plan.

Comment: basically there are the same.

Comment: Test the two across a large number of iterations. See which one is better for you usage.

Comment: Yes I know they are same but I am thinking about efficiency

Comment: What does "efficiency" mean? Are you talking about performance, easier coding and maintenance, or something else? If you're talking about performance, then just try it: run both queries, check the execution plans, and see if there's any difference. And note that the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682(v=sql.100).aspx) says that either `OR` and `IN` will return the same results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are same 
SQL server converts this

```
where @TeamId in (Team1Id, Team2Id)
```

Into

```
where @TeamId=Team1Id or @TeamId=Team2Id
```

It's better to write IN compare to OR more readable and easy.

Comment: IN(...) is merely what you see, Pawan.  It is a temporary convenience for the programmer and the syntax has nothing to do with the relative efficiency of the query versus a series of OR conditions. They are different ways of expressing the same conditionalities.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific example yo provide, of testing a variable, IN is simply syntactic sugar for multiple OR's.

However in the related case of selecting rows of a relation the use of a join to another relation is superior, particulalry if the data field being compared is indexed or the list of comparison values grows. Such a comparison relation is easily created using a static sub-query like this:

```
select *
from data
join (
  select Team1Id as TeamId union all
  select Team2Id 
) comparison on comparison.TeamId = data.TeamId
```

This technique of a static sub-query is widely applicable to many circumstances.